# MVVM and Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, mvvm, unity-container

I am currently learning the MVVM pattern, and the tutorial I am following uses Unity for DI.  I haven't really used DI in this way before and just wanted clarification of my thoughts on how this specific code works.

In the View I have:

```
private ViewModel vm;

    [Dependency]
    public ViewModel VM
    {
        set
        {
            vm = value;
            this.DataContext = vm;
        }

    }
```

where the dependency attribute is telling Unity to inject here.  The ViewModel constructor takes an IQuoteSource object which is registered with Unity as such:

```
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        RandomQuoteSource randomQuoteSource = new RandomQuoteSource();
        container.RegisterInstance<IQuoteSource>(randomQuoteSource);
        MainWindow window = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        window.Show();
```

How exactly does this work, as I am never explicitly creating an object of the ViewModel using the property above.  Is this all handled within Unity, if so how does it achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't have much to do with the MVVM pattern per se, other than the fact that the view's dependency on its ViewModel is resolved via dependency injection.

For how this works, it's pretty simple. There are 3 simple concepts for DI:

The first is **declaring a dependency**, where some object specifies that it depends on something, either via a constructor or a property (which was the case in your example, using the `DependencyAttribute`).

The second concept is *registration*, where you **register an implementation** of the dependencies your objects have (in your case, you registered an implementation of the `IQuoteSource`). Note that you didn't have to *register* the ViewModel, because it's not really an implementation of an interface that you depend on.

The third is what glues things together, which is **resolving the dependencies**, where you ask the container to resolve some type for you, and it goes and looks at what dependencies that object *declared* (in your case, you're resolving the `MainWindow` which has a dependency on the `ViewModel`), finds the right *registered* implementation and resolves it. This behavior cascades through the resolution of the graph of objects (which resolves the dependency of the ViewModel on the `IQuoteSource`).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it `MainWindow` which the VM property belongs to? If not I'm assuming that resolving a `MainWindow` starts some sort of resolve cascade which at some point includes creating the object which has the VM property in your example.

Unity examines each object it has to resolve within the cascade for properties decorated with `[Dependency]`, and creates an object of the dependent property type. When it creates objects like this it picks the constructor which has the most parameters it knows how to create, which is where your registration of IQuoteSource -> RandomQuoteSource comes in.

Comment: Hi, yes VM is a property of MainWindow.  Thanks.